# iOS Objective C Check if Object Exists at Index

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have some code to grab an item from an index:

```
        NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[webView.URL absoluteURL]];
        NSArray *listItems = [fullUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"?url="];

        NSString *urlString = [listItems objectAtIndex:1];
        if (urlString != (id)[NSNull null]) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
        } else {
            //fallback just in case
            [self loadBaseURL];
        }
```

It ended up erroring on this line:

```
NSString *urlString = [listItems objectAtIndex:1];
```

Which I thought I was checking for in the following line for null. It seems like I need some check beforehand to ensure that the objectAtIndex:1 exists before grabbing it. What's the best format to write this in?

Comment: Use `NSURLComponents` if you need parse URL

Comment: The test should be instead: `if ([listItems count] > 1) { } else {}`

Comment: https://nshipster.com/nsurl/ . <-- NSURLComponents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error to say

```
[listItems objectAtIndex:1]
```

if there is no such index. So your first step should be to examine `listItems.count`. If your proposed index is greater than or equal to that number, don’t use it.